# I get warning when creating delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using [MPGTextField](https://github.com/gaurvw/MPGTextField). At the `.h` file, I get the following warning:

> Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'delegate', it
>   will be implemented by its superclass, use @dynamic to acknowledge
>   intention

Here is the code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MPGTextFieldDelegate;

@interface MPGTextField : UITextField <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

// Here is where I get the warning:
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MPGTextFieldDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> delegate;
```

What is wrong, and how can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your `MPGTextField` inherits from `UITextField` which already has property named `delegate`.
To fix the warning just write following in the implementation file:
//MPGTextField.m

```
@dynamic delegate;  
@implementation MPGTextField
//...
@end
```

Or make a new property and use that one, something like this:
`@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MPGTextFieldDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> myDelegate;`

```
@implementation MPGTextField
//...
- (void)setMyDelegate:(id <MPGTextFieldDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>)myDelegate 
{
    _myDelegate = myDelegate;
    self.delegate = myDelegate;
}
@end
```

Comment: Can I just change the "delegate" to another name?

Comment: Where should @dynamic go?

Comment: As I said, in the implementation file, above `@implementation` line

Answer (score 0):

Also I have a StepRecipeViewController (UIViewController). I want to pass information from StepRecipeContainerPageViewController to StepRecipeViewController.

This has been my solution.

The StepRecipeContainerPageViewController class:

```
@protocol StepRecipeContainerPageViewControllerDelegate<NSObject>
-(void) passInformation :(NSString*)someInfo;
@end

@interface StepRecipeContainerPageViewController : UIPageViewController<StepRecipeContainerPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource>{}

@property (assign, nonatomic) id <UIPageViewControllerDelegate, StepRecipeContainerPageViewControllerDelegate> myDelegate;
```

I call this function in this class:

```
[self.myDelegate passInformation:@"works"];
```

The StepRecipeViewController class:

```
#import "StepRecipeContainerPageViewController.h"    
@interface StepRecipeViewController : UIViewController<StepRecipeContainerPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>{}

@implementation StepRecipeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

StepRecipeContainerPageViewController *vc = [[StepRecipeContainerPageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"StepRecipeContainerPageViewController" bundle:nil];
    [vc setMyDelegate:self];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }

-(void) passInformation :(NSString*)someInfo{
        NSLog(@"Other class %@",someInfo);
}
```